# Convert a pyspark dataframe value to a variable string value

Tags: dataframe, datetime, variables, type-conversion

I would like to convert a dataframe date value to a variable to use in other places.
I have a df

```
.... DateValue
     2020-05-25
```

What I would like is `'2020-05-25'`

Using `df.groupBy("DateValue").avg().collect()[0][0]`

I get `datetime.date(2020, 5, 25)`

I would like to convert that to `'2020-05-25'`

Comment: are you looking for [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)? to get yyyy-mm-dd, the [format](https://strftime.org/) would e.g. be '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: yes! Thank you! .strftime('%Y-%m-%d') added at the end gave me what i was looking for.